# Assembly - What does a standalone label do?

Tags: assembly

What does a standalone label do (generically) in assembly languages. Below is an excerpt of 8080 assembly code.

Does the label `FNDLP` refer to the same instruction as `FL1`?

Does `FNDNXT` refer to the location containing the first `INX D` instruction? And the fact that it is in its own line (unlike `FL2`) simply a style thing?

```
FNDLP:                                  ;*** FDLNP ***
FL1:    PUSH H                          ;SAVE LINE #
        LHLD TXTUNF                     ;CHECK IF WE PASSED END
        ...

FNDNXT:                                 ;*** FNDNXT ***
        INX  D                          ;FIND NEXT LINE
FL2:    INX  D                          ;JUST PASSED BYTE 1 & 2
```

Comment: Think of a label as a zero-width point that refers to the *start* of whatever comes next, not to the whole instruction or function that follows.  Given just the label, there's no information about size, just a single point location (an address).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the label FNDLP refer to the same instruction as FL1?

Yes, usually a label simply creates a symbolic name for the next memory location that would be populated. Hence you could just as easily have used something like:

```
LABEL1:
LABEL2:
LABEL3:
LABEL4:
LABEL5:   DSW R7        ;; the very handy do-something-with instruction :-)
```

and *all* those labels would refer to the `DSW` location. If it helps, it may be better to think of it conceptually as:

```
FNDLP:
FL1:
        PUSH H                          ;SAVE LINE #
```

since that seems to *clearly* separate the labels from the actual instruction.